# Is it possible to import 3 tables data into just one Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to import 3 tables data into just one Table, if so can you please shows us the code.

I have three tables and to display data all together, I have to use these join statements.

```
    select  *
    from [runners 2000-2005] 
    join races on races.race ID = [runners 2000-2005].race ID
    join results on results.race ID = [runners 2000-2005].race ID
    where 1=1
```

I use a race ID to link all the tables together cause it is common column in all tables

but i thought would it be better if i could import the data from TABLE results and races into runners 2000-2005 . Making one big table.

thx I hope this helps Paul Im a newbie.

Comment: "please shows us the code" is not really what this site is about. You need to detail what you know currently, what you have tried and demonstrate a basic understanding of the subject

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Details are impossible to give with your very vague and unclear question ..... please study [How to I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and embrace it!

Comment: ok i'll provide more detail

Comment: So you want to use display the data from all three tables in a single UI element? Why not just create a **view** on top of these three tables and then displaying the result of that view? No point in copying around and duplicating data!

Comment: ok you see i newbie i don't know everything I don't know how a view works but i will lookitup to study

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as noted it is a bit vague, but you are also `JOINING` the tables upside down, as I cannot see the [race ID] being listed in the [runners] table, that would mean you have runners duplicated and the results would not correlate to the runners as there is no relation. I might also be way of mark as you didn't provide a schema, so I am taking liberty with the table schemas and using something I would expect.

Maybe try something like this

```
CREATE TABLE [runners 2000-2005] ([Runner ID] INT, [First Name] NVARCHAR(200), [Last Name] NVARCHAR(200), [Other Details] NVARCHAR(500) )
CREATE TABLE [races] ([Race ID] INT, [Race Name] VARCHAR(200), [Race Location] VARCHAR(200))
CREATE TABLE [results] ([Race ID] INT, [Position] INT, [Runner ID] INT)

SELECT 
T1.[Race ID]
, T1.[Race Name]
, T1.[Race Location]

, T2.[Runner ID]
, T2.Position

, T3.[First Name]
, T3.[Last Name]
, T3.[Other Details]

INTO [all race details 2000-2005] /*Remove this line if you just want a query*/
FROM races AS T1
INNER JOIN results AS [T2] ON T2.[Race ID] = T1.[Race ID]
INNER JOIN [runners 2000-2005] AS [T3] ON T3.[Runner ID] = T2.[Runner ID]

SELECT * 
FROM [all race details 2000-2005]
```

Is use table aliases just to shorten the query, also I find it easier to first select from the table with the most common information or sits on top of the hierarchy, which is the `races` table in my opinion.

First there is a race, then some finish order to the race and then the details of the runners in the race.

The `SELECT...INTO...FROM` will create a fresh table, otherwise you can `CREATE TABLE...INSERT INTO TABLE.. SELECT` up to you.

Comment: thx alot thx i'll try this i hope this post helps others not just me thx